# Safari: White-space: nowrap makes my container gain 2px in width

Tags: html, css, safari

This is a very straight forward issue that has been driving me insane. So I want to make ellipsis work on a `span` element that is inside a `button` element.

The ellipsis works, I get to see the 3 dots, however when I apply this code, my button 'gains' 2 px in width and the whole layout of element is gone.

This is my HTML struture:

```
<button type="button">
   <div>
         <span class="ellipsis-20">Offer</span>
         <span class="ellipsis-20"><%= promotion.promotion_list %></span>
   </div>
</button>
```

My CSS for the `span`:

```
.ellipsis-20 {
  .multiLineEllipsis(20px, 1);
}

.multiLineEllipsis(@lineHeight: 20px, @lineCount: 1) {
  width: 100%;

  line-height: @lineHeight;
  max-height: @lineHeight * @lineCount;

  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

If I remove the `white-space: nowrap;`, the extra width is gone, but I don't see the 3 dots. Also I tried adding a `calc(100% - 2px)` and I got the same result. Does anyone know of a fix, specifically, for safari that can point me in the right direction?

EDIT: my `span` has `display: inline-block` as well

Comment: Could you provide a jsFiddle without any server side or less logic?

Comment: This question is more oriented to someone who might have came across this issue before, as I can't replicate this issue in JSFiddle.